# «Undefined reference» when using an URL in Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, urls

I'm trying to cite a Webpage in a latex report but it always fails during the compilation.
Here is my *.tex* :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

% Commandes personnalisées

\title{My lovely test}
\author{Me}
\date{10/23/13}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
I love to use Google\cite{google}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr-fr}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

And my *.bib*

```
@misc{
google,
Author={Google},
Howpublished={\url{http://www.google.com}},
Title={Google what else}
}
```

But when compiling, I've got this error:

> l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{1}
>                                  [1] ! Undefined control sequence. l.6 ...eauteurs\bgroup Google\egroup\egroup{}, \og
>                                                      Google what else\fg{}. ! Undefined control sequence. l.6 ...le\egroup\egroup{},
>   \og Google what else\fg
>                                                     {}. (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd)) [2] (./test.aux)

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What happens if you remove `.bib` from the `\bibliography{bibliography.bib}` instruction?

Comment: Same problem: `LaTeX Warning: Citation 'google' on page 1 undefined on input line 15.

(./test.bbl [1]
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 ...eauteurs\bgroup Google\egroup\egroup{}, \og
                                                   Google what else\fg{}.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 ...le\egroup\egroup{}, \og Google what else\fg
                                                  {}.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd)) [2] (./test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
`

Comment: I think you have to use the `ieeetr-fr` bibliography style in conjunction with a specific class or package.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the name, `ieeetr-fr` is an adaptation of the IEEE style for use in French. As such, it hard-codes in an assumption that `babel` is loaded with the `french` option to define for example `\fg`. You will either need to load `babel` appropriately or use a different style (say the standard IEEE one).